# How to carry variables into different function

Tags: python-3.x

First of all sorry for this heavy, blunt code. 
I know there are some better and more eye-candy codes out there but I decided to write it by myself. I know there is a room for HUGE improvement but bear with me.

Almost all my code is working surprisingly except the score part.

Basically this is a Rock Paper Scissors game with recording the number of wins for player, for computer and total number of games.

I only couldn't pass the scores into another function. Can someone please let me know why I am getting this error when I am selecting "1 - Score" on repeat game function

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "forweb.py", line 123, in <module>
    main_menu()
  File "forweb.py", line 27, in main_menu
    play_game()
  File "forweb.py", line 95, in play_game
    return player, computer, total, repeat_game()
  File "forweb.py", line 112, in repeat_game
    play_game()
  File "forweb.py", line 47, in play_game
    play_game()
  File "forweb.py", line 95, in play_game
    return player, computer, total, repeat_game()
  File "forweb.py", line 107, in repeat_game
    print("Total Game: "+ play_game(total))
NameError: name 'total' is not defined
```

note: please ignore "from game_text import game_information" since it is on another python file

```
import random
import sys
import os
import time
from game_text import game_information
os.system('clear')
name = input("Please write your name: ")

def main_menu():

  menu_selection_word = input("1-Help, 2-Play, 3-Quit \n"))
  try:
    menu_selection_int = int(menu_selection_word)
    print("you have selected: ", menu_selection_int)
  except ValueError:
    print(" Invalid selection")
    main_menu()

  if menu_selection_int == 1:
    os.system('clear')
    game_information()
    main_menu()
  elif menu_selection_int == 2:
    play_game()
  elif menu_selection_int == 3:
    game_quit()
  else:
    print("Invaild selection \n")
    main_menu()

def play_game(player=0,computer=0,total=0):
  total += 1
  player_selection_input = input("R-Rock, S-Scissors, P-Paper \n")

  if player_selection_input == "R" or player_selection_input == "r":
    print("You have selected Rock")
  elif player_selection_input == "S" or player_selection_input == "s":
    print("You have selected Scissors")
  elif player_selection_input == "P" or player_selection_input == "p":
    print("You have selected Paper")
  else:
    print("Invaild selection \n")
    play_game()

  comp_random = ["R", "r", "S", "s", "P", "p"]
  comp_selection = random.choice(comp_random)

  if comp_selection == "R" or comp_selection == "r":        
    print("Computer Selected: Rock")
  elif comp_selection == "P" or comp_selection == "p":      
    print("Computer Selected: Paper")
  else:     
    print("Computer Selected: Scissors")

  if player_selection_input == "R" or player_selection_input == "r":
    if comp_selection == "S" or comp_selection == "s":
        print("Your Rock crushed computer's scissors! You Won!")
        player += 1
        time.sleep(1.5)
    elif comp_selection == "R" or comp_selection == "r":
        print("It is a tie!")
        time.sleep(1.5)
    else:
        print("Computer's Paper covered your Rock! You Lost!")
        computer += 1
        time.sleep(1.5)
  elif player_selection_input == "S" or player_selection_input == "s":
    if comp_selection == "S" or comp_selection == "s":
        print(" It is a tie!")
        time.sleep(1.5)
    elif comp_selection == "R" or comp_selection == "r":
        print("Computer's Rock crushed your Scissors. You Lost!")
        computer += 1
        time.sleep(1.5)
    else:
        print("Your Scissors cut computer's Paper. You Won!")
        player += 1
        time.sleep(1.5)
  elif player_selection_input == "P" or player_selection_input == "p":
    if comp_selection == "R" or comp_selection == "r":
        print("Your Paper covered computer's Rock. You Won!")
        player += 1
        time.sleep(1.5)
    elif comp_selection == "S" or comp_selection == "s":
        print("Computer's Scissors cut your Paper. You Lost!")
        computer += 1
        time.sleep(1.5)
    else:
        print(" It is a tie!")
        time.sleep(1.5) 
  return player, computer, total, repeat_game()

def repeat_game():  
  repeat_game_selection = input("1-Score, 2-New game, 3-Quit \n")

  try:
    repeat_game_select = int(repeat_game_selection)
  except ValueError:
    print(" Invalid selection")
    repeat_game()
  if repeat_game_select == 1:
    os.system('clear')
    print("Total Game: "+ play_game(total))
    Print("Player Win: "+ play_game(player))
    print("Computer Win: "+ play_game(computer))
  elif repeat_game_select == 2: 
    print("New Game begins \n")
    play_game()
  elif repeat_game_select == 3:
    game_quit()
  else:
    print("Invaild selection \n")
    repeat_game()

def game_quit():
  os.system('clear')
  sys.exit("Thank you for Playing. See you next time!")

main_menu()
```

Comment: As the error states your `total` variable is undefined when you're trying to access it in `repeat_game` since you probably defined it in one of the other functions. The code you posted is not properly indented and cannot be run - I suggest you fix that so that people will be able to understand it better and try to help you.

Comment: yeah just modified to show the indents correctly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You want to pair

```
    return player, computer, total, repeat_game()
```

with a call like this:

```
    player, computer, total, repeat_game = play_game()
```

That is, if the public API returns four values, you will want to pick up those values.

Four is starting to become an inconveniently largish number.
You'd probably be better off defining a `class` and storing four object attributes,
such as `self.player`.

Comment: Thank you.. I havent studied the class section yet. This code is outcome of the things that I cover so far. 

Such as, loops, conditions, lists and functions. 

thank you

thank you